# How to calculate the global minimum variance portfolio in R?

Tags: programming, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization

I am attempting to use the `globalMin.portfolio` command to calculate the global minimum variance portfolio in RStudio. My code is as follows (note that several libraries have been included which may not be necessary, since I am unclear which ones are needed to carry out the functions):

```
#Libraries
library(corpcor)
library(tseries)
library(fPortfolio)
library(quadprog)
library(SharpeR)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
library(zoo)
library(plotly)
library(portfolio.r)
library(portfolio_noshorts.r)

rk.free=0.005

rm( list=ls() )
portfolio <- read.csv2("File Directory/Document.csv")
T <- nrow(portfolio)
portfolio <- portfolio[ seq(T,1,-1) , ]
stock1_r<- diff(log(portfolio$stock1))*100
stock2_r <- diff(log(portfolio$stock2))*100
stock3_r<- diff(log(portfolio$stock3))*100
stock4_r <- diff(log(portfolio$stock4))*100
stock5_r    <- diff(log(portfolio$stock5))*100
stock6_r<- diff(log(portfolio$stock6))*100
stock7_r<- diff(log(portfolio$stock7))*100
stock8_r<- diff(log(portfolio$t))*100
stock9_r<- diff(log(portfolio$stock9))*100
stock10_r<- diff(log(portfolio$stock10))*100

portfolio_r <- data.frame(stock1_r, stock2_r, stock3_r, stock4_r, stock5_r, stock6_r, stock7_r, stock8_r, stock9_r, stock10_r)
er1=c(mean(stock1_r), mean(stock2_r), mean(stock3_r), mean(stock4_r), mean(stock5_r), mean(stock6_r), mean(stock7_r), mean(stock8_r), mean(stock9_r), mean(stock10_r))

#Covariance Matrix
covmat1<-cov(portfolio_r)

#Shrinkage estimate of covariance
cov.shrink(portfolio_r)

#Transform covariance to correlation matrix
cov2cor(covmat1)
ew1=rep(1,10)/10
er1
covmat1
ew1

#Compute global minimum variance portfolio
gmin.port = globalMin.portfolio(er1, covmat1)
attributes(gmin.port)
print(gmin.port)
summary(gmin.port, rk.free=r.free)
plot(gmin.port, col="blue")
```

However, when I attempt to calculate the global minimum variance portfolio, I simply get the error message; `"Error: could not find function "globalMin.portfolio"`. This happens even though the expected return (`er1`) and covariance matrix (`covmat1`) are calculated and output is shown when the program is run. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: getting the same problem myself, how did you get the function to work? Thanks!

Comment: Please do not remove contact from questions. This website is collaborative so any question asked here is meant to remain available with its full content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last 2 calls must be changed from

```
library(portfolio.r) 

library(portfolio_noshorts.r)
```

to

```
source(portfolio.r)

source(portfolio_noshorts.r)
```

The correct files must be availbale at [http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/](http://Econometrics%20Webpage).

Comment: That did not work. It does not appear to be a problem with the library since the code works when running this example: http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/testport.r

Comment: testport.r is sourcing portfolio_noshorts.r at the begining

Comment: It worked. Had to make some modifications in the code.